# Capture specific CALayer (and subviews) to a video file (or data) in Real Time

Tags: iphone, ios5, uiimageview, calayer, cgimage

I have a UIView (with its CALayer) which has a `UIImageView` as a sub-view.
The UIImageView is animated (`imageView.animationImages`).

I would like to capture the currently played animation to a video file, or video data (later to be converted to a video file), but not capture all the elements on the screen, like buttons and other UI, but just a specific UIView (not for a promo vid, but as part of the app's functionality).

I tried implementing [ScreenCaptureView](http://aroth.no-ip.org:82/wordpress/archives/673) , but while it does let me capture a specific `UIView` into a video file in *realtime*, it won't capture the Animated `UIImageView` , it shows just the first frame...

I thought about using the CALayer's `renderInContext:` and then somehow appending the `CGImage` (current frame) to a video data and then making a video file from the data (or maybe appending directly to a video file).

I'm kinda stuck on the appending part... I don't really know what to do with the render data of the current frame.

Does anyone have any hints or suggestions?

Any help will be much appreciated :)

Comment: FYI in case it helps, I implemented this by creating a cvpixelbufferpool and then rendering the CALayer into a pixelbuffer with a CGBitmapContext. Then I add the pixelbuffer into an AVAssetWriter.

Answer (score 1):

I made the a change to `ScreenCaptureView.m` and now it captures the `UIImageView` animation:

```
[self.layer renderInContext:context];
```

**changed to:**

```
[self.layer.presentationLayer renderInContext:context];
```

Although the performance is actually pretty bad on a device (iPhone 4)...

Comment: Did you get anywhere on improving the performance? I'm working on a similar thing, and getting slammed with the performance of the renderInContext.